# GWT List Grid performance

Tags: performance, gwt

I have a gwt list grid which i need to show more than 1000 messages.
But it takes 40millsec to display each message. So it is very slow.
Can u help me so that i can show all messages in less time.
Thanks Nagaraju

Comment: What are your "messages"?  If they are Widgets (e.g., Labels, Panels, etc.) then you could save some time by making them simply Elements (e.g., DivElements, SpanElements)

Answer (score 2):

As Bogdan said paging is your best bet.

However if your requirement strictly needs you to have the 1000+ lines at one time I would reconsider the grid approach.

When you are working with such a large amount of elements an iterative dom "touch" will be dirt slow.

See if you can rather create a component that gets the messages into String form with their markup. Then set the inner HTML once. You can then use something like jquery or gwtquery to attach handlers to the elements in a timely fashion.

Failing that you could use a lazy render method where you render only whats on-screen but that gets much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering this 2 Year old question Just for Kicks -**

1. GWT has progressed a lot since 2 Years.
2. GWT provides hell lot of options to User to do performance tuning.
3. GWT as done a lot of perormance tuning on widgets. GWT 2.5 has Cell
   Widgets like CellList/CellTable/DataGrid which make displaying large
   data easier , faster and with light weight heavy DOM.

### Reference -

**https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets**

### Summary  -

Cell widgets (data presentation widgets) are high-performance, lightweight widgets composed of Cells for displaying data. Examples are lists, tables, trees and browsers. These widgets are designed to handle and display very large sets of data quickly. A cell widget renders its user interface as an HTML string, using innerHTML instead of traditional DOM manipulation. This design follows the flyweight pattern where data is accessed and cached only as needed, and passed to flyweight Cell objects. A cell widget can accept data from any type of data source. ***The data model handles asynchronous updates as well as push updates. When you change the data, the view is automatically updated***.

In addition, cells can override onBrowserEvent to act as a flyweight that handles events that are fired on elements that were rendered by the cell.

### Note -

1) CellTable being capable of displaying large data also come with Pager options and also AutoPage on Scrolling option ( example [CellList](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) )

2) Also, if you come across any other performance issues in GWT you can call in the ***Bazooka features of GWT*** - SpeedTracer, Logging, Chrome Dev tools Profiling, GWT Light Weight Metrics, Code Splitting, GWT Compiler Metrics, GWT Closure Compiler, Resource Bundling to *crush* it !!!!

Answer (score 0):

1000 items for a web-based application is too much. Try implementing some sort of paging algorithm. You could look at the [PagingScrollTable](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=PagingScrollTable) from gwt incubator ;)

Comment: [BulkTableRenderers](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=BulkTableRenderers) could also be of some help (though, 1000 messages is still too much). GWT 2.1 is supposed to include similar (based on the experiences from gwt-incubator) Widgets - it might be worth checking out the latest milestones releases for GWT 2.1.